# Export X509Certificate with Powershell and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, certificate, x509certificate

I have a Powershell script that exports an X509Certificate of user abc and it works fine when running in terminal.

```
$user = "abc"
$pfx_file = "pfxFilePath.pfx"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "123" -Force -AsPlainText
(Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\currentuser\my\) | where-object { $_.subject -like "*$user*"} | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $pfx_file -Password $pass -Verbose
```

However, it doesn't export anything when I invoke it with my C# test(with PowerShell SDK) in Visual Studio, there is no message - no message, no error message, no verbose message. And I really don't know how to troubleshoot the problem. Here is my code

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
await ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted").InvokeAsync();
ps.AddScript("".\\test.ps1");
var results = await ps.InvokeAsync();
```

I think this is related to user permissions, but I used the same user for both Visual Studio and terminal, how can I check which user is running the test in Visual Studio? Is there anything can help me troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks!

Edit: After some digging, I realized the problem is with PowerShell SDK. It doesn't use regular Windows PowerShell instance, it has a different PSModulePath and it is missing a lot of default modules.

Comment: First of all, use `PowerShell.Create(InitialSessionState)` with `InitialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy` set to `ByPass`. Second, first command is `Start-Transcript` with args. Check `ps.HadErrors` and `ps.Streams` to get more information.

Comment: You can't change `ExecutionPolicy` of running powershell normally. You should create it with apropriate `ExecutionPolicy`

Comment: I would think you would want to keep this in native C# .NET, rather than spawn out to a separate PowerShell script.  Something like: Create a new X509Store.  Open the store.  Enumerate Certificates collection.  Get the X509Certificate from the collection where Subject property matches.  Call one of the X509Certificate Export methods to save it to a PFX file.  Close the store.